# Android Studio Cannot resolve symbol R

Tags: android, android-studio

I’m having this problem in a project. If I open a previous project, it works. If I create a new one, it doesn’t work. It doesn't even complete the build, keeps stuck on executing tasks. So I guess it’s not a xml problem, since it’s happening to all new projects. This bug started yesterday.

I already tried these solutions:

**-Clean and build**
(It takes forever on “executing tasks”. Usually when it’s around 20 or 30 minutes I close the project. – My gradle is already set to work offline and it does great in previous projects)

**-Reinstall platform build tools**

Also, I got this external ide error some minutes ago.

```
 No message
com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.model.ExternalSystemException: 
    at org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.service.project.GradleExecutionHelper.execute(GradleExecutionHelper.java:238)
    at com.android.tools.idea.gradle.invoker.GradleTasksExecutor.invokeGradleTasks(GradleTasksExecutor.java:416)
    at com.android.tools.idea.gradle.invoker.GradleTasksExecutor.run(GradleTasksExecutor.java:222)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager$TaskRunnable.run(CoreProgressManager.java:563)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager$2.run(CoreProgressManager.java:142)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.registerIndicatorAndRun(CoreProgressManager.java:446)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.executeProcessUnderProgress(CoreProgressManager.java:392)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.ProgressManagerImpl.executeProcessUnderProgress(ProgressManagerImpl.java:54)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.runProcess(CoreProgressManager.java:127)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.ProgressManagerImpl$1.run(ProgressManagerImpl.java:126)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl$8.run(ApplicationImpl.java:366)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
    at org.jetbrains.ide.PooledThreadExecutor$1$1.run(PooledThreadExecutor.java:55)
```

I have no clue what else I can do. Please help me.

Main Activity

```
    package example.appmedico;

import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;




public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    Button btProx, btEsp;
    TextView tvAche;
    Context ctx = this;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


        tvAche = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.tvAche);
        btProx = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btProx);
        btProx.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                Intent intent = new Intent(ctx,NearbyActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });



    }
```

XML

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="example.appmedico.MainActivity"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:text="Ache médicos por:"
        android:id="@+id/tvAche"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Proximidade"
        android:id="@+id/btProx"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Especialidade"
        android:id="@+id/btEsp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Check your xml / layout files for errors. If there is an error in one, the R file will not build

Comment: I already checked. It is happening even in newly created projects where I didn't touch the code...

Comment: If its taking ages to build in a simple project, it will never generate the R file in a timely manner. Same with cleaning. It sounds like your gradle is running extremely slowly. To which I can only suggest trying to update all your tools to the latest (sounds like you may have done this already). Other than that I am unsure. Possibly re-installing Android Studio entirely. though this may be wasted effort too

Comment: I'm just guessing here but try to delete the entire build folder. Don't expect any answer soon, by the way. Gradle exceptions in the build progress are not that common. :(

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Finally it worked. When I invalidated caches and restarted the R error was gone, but everything was still very slow. I've try many solutions, but in the end I decided to delete many files to clean my computer (almost 100G was gone). Now it works fine, up to 2 or 4 minutes for graddle to build.

Answer (score 1):

Try restart/invalidate cache, or delete .iml file and import project

Answer (score 0):

Open Build.gradle(Project level)

remove everything after your android studio version in dependencies like alhpa  or beta something.

Example:
My Android Studio version is 2.2.2 so my dependencies will be:

```
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2.2'

    // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
    // in the individual module build.gradle files
}
```

Answer (score -1):

The simplest way to solve it is to create a new project and add the previous project code to it, it is likely you have an error in code or resources name.

Also try to rebuild the project.

If it doesn't work then the go to File/Invalidate Caches Restart

Comment: Thanks, but the problem is, every new project I start makes the same error without changing the code. I just create it, and the R is not found.

Comment: Then i will suggest you to reinstall android studio